# Prevent Magento to empty cart after failed payments

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, payment, shopping-cart

How can I stop Magento to empty cart after the customer fails to pay with a card?

The customer can use a different card but the cart already becomes empty and he/she needs to put all the items back into card again which makes the site loose customer.

Comment: In Magneto 1.x there is no out of the box solution. I did this on a custom payment method by getting the latest quote and repopulating the cart. If you are interested I can share my code

Comment: That will be perfect if you can share your code @Yiorgos Moschovitis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your payment method's controller you'll have an action for **failed/rejected/canceled** orders.

Let's say it's called `failAction()`. Then you can add something like the following to your function.

```
public function failAction() {
...
    if(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId()){
        if ($lastQuoteId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastQuoteId()){
            $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($lastQuoteId);
            $quote->setIsActive(true)->save();
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('module_name')->__('Inform the customer for failed transaction'));
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart'); //Redirect to cart
        return;
    }
...
 }
```

Comment: sorry, it was not helped to me.

Comment: It worked, but in my failure screen, after running your code, when I check Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart() it says it's empty, and after moving to other page then the cart is loaded again...

Comment: I'm not redirecting users to 'checkout/cart' as you suggest, I'm loading the failure screen, and there, my minicart says there are no items. When moving to other page everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php this file is the actual controller file, but depends up on the payment method extensions it will change with Namespace/Modulename/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php

Find function saveOrderAction()

find these lines

```
$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();
        /**
         * when there is redirect to third party, we don't want to save order yet.
         * we will save the order in return action.
         */
        if (isset($redirectUrl)) {
            $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
        }

        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```

comment this line `//$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();`
and add below codes inside the if condition so the condition will look like ..

```
    if (isset($redirectUrl)) {
                $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
                $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->setIsActive(1) ;
            }
    $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();
   $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```

This is i have done with the third party Payment extension.

Comment: This solution is creating the order before trying the payment. But if you cancel several times and then go to MyAccount/MyOrders you'll see all the tries, all the orders. I just want to keep the quote but not the orders. Didn't work for me..

Comment: It was worked for me when i am using default checkout in my magento theme. but when i used IWD onepage checkout, it is not worked.

Comment: May be iwd onepage is using some other function, i haven't checked with this

Answer (score 0):

For Naveen answer, if any one using IWD extension, then function saveOrderAction() is in app/code/community/IWD/Opc/controllers/JsonController.php

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solutions for **Magento 2.3.5**. Please override **Failure.php**(Core file path: /vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage) and change *public function* as below

```
public function execute()
{
    
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $_checkoutSession = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
    $_quoteFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
    
    $order = $_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
    $quote = $_quoteFactory->create()->loadByIdWithoutStore($order->getQuoteId());
    if ($quote->getId()) {
        $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null)->save();
        $_checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
        //$this->messageManager->addWarningMessage('Payment Failed.');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working at all why everyone is replying the same answer while it's not working.