# Re-adding products to cart on payment failure requires refresh

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, addtocart

I referred this url ([Prevent Magento to empty cart after failed payments](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93271/prevent-magento-to-empty-cart-after-failed-payments)) and came up with the following code to add the products back again to the cart.

```
public function failureAction()
{ 
    $lastQuoteId = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getLastQuoteId();
    $lastOrderId = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getLastOrderId();        

    if ($lastQuoteId && $lastOrderId) {
        $orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($lastOrderId);
        $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($lastQuoteId);
        $quote->setIsActive(true)->save();
    }
    if (!$lastQuoteId || !$lastOrderId) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart', array("_forced_secure" => true));
        return;
    }

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();  
}
```

I'm displaying a page on the failureAction which the 3rd party payment gateway redirects. The problem is that when the payment gateway redirects and the page is shown for the first time, the cart is displayed as empty. When i refresh the page the products get added to the cart. How can i achieve this without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote Object `$quote` does **not set active** at current **checkout session until page refresh**.So face this issue.

As per as,magento **anysession variable does effect until one rendere**.

So ,i would suggesting you create `another Action (example: testAction())` and

after doing  `$quote->setIsActive(true)->save();` redirect to that testAction url by `$this->_redirect('*/*/test');` and your testAction and create an view

```
public function testAction()
    { 
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();  
    }
```