# Magento 2: How to restore the cart after canceled/failed payment?

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento-2.1.7

I used following code, but it doesn't work, I still get an empty cart.

```
$comment = __('Payment has been canceled.');
if ($order->getId() && $order->getState() != Order::STATE_CANCELED) {
    $order->registerCancellation($comment)->save();
}
$session->restoreQuote();
$this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage($comment);
$this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
```

Comment: Is the $session the Magento\Checkout\Model\Session, right?

Comment: @Nikolas, yes, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one, it works for me in Magento 2.4:
(inspired by [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93285/92286))

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory;

class MyAction extends Action
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $checkoutSession,
        QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->quoteFactory    = $quoteFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $id = $this->checkoutSession->getLastQuoteId();
        $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->loadByIdWithoutStore($id);
        if (!$quote->getId()) {
            // enter your code on fail (if quote not found) here.
            // action method must return Result object, not boolean.
            return false;
        }
        $quote->setIsActive(true)->setReservedOrderId(null)->save();
        $this->checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
        // action method must return Result object, not boolean.
        // write your redirect, JSON, or other result here.
        return true;
    }
}
```